# python get rank of dicts in a list

Tags: python

Consider the following:

```
from random import random
data = [{'label': 'one', 'count': random()}, {'label': 'two', 'count': random()}, {'label': 'three', 'count': random()}]

for row in data:
    row['score'] = row['count']*2

data = sorted(data, key=lambda k: k['score'], reverse=True)
```

I would like each dict in the `data` list to further have a column `rank` that has the integer rank 0-n of the value of its `score` category.

Comment: How do you want to assign `rank`? The higher the score, the higher the rank?

Comment: exactly. the index of the dict in the list after `sorted` is called

Answer (score 0):

You have already sorted the list. So all you need to do is iterate over the list and assign them rank
Try this:

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    data[i]['rank'] = i+1
```

Output:

> [{'count': 0.6629962329614308, 'score': 1.3259924659228617, 'rank': 1, 'label': 'one'}, {'count': 0.5252504729422107, 'score': 1.0505009458844214, 'rank': 2, 'label': 'three'}, {'count': 0.0887804798621562, 'score': 0.1775609597243124, 'rank': 3, 'label': 'two'}]